# The difference between parsing using a string or a stream (Poco c++)

Tags: json, saxparser, poco-libraries

I have written a simple hierarchical json-parser, using POCO JSON, to be used as a sax parser.
Is their any difference in the result if i use a string or a stream as input to the parse method, see call below, or are the different constructors equivalent?

```
Parser parser;
DefaultHandler handler;
parser.setHandler(&handler);
parser.parse(input);
```

In terms of memory consumption, speed etc?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

std::string version is just a [wrapper](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/blob/develop/JSON/include/Poco/JSON/Parser.h#L107) that creates stream on your behalf, so at the end the total will be roughly the same, string is just more convenient for user.

[EDIT]

This was changed for 1.5.2 - wrapping was removed so that now both (stream and string) versions iterate. The [Benchmark Example](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/blob/develop/JSON/samples/Benchmark/src/Benchmark.cpp#L98) can be used to determine how much is stream slower than string.

[/EDIT]

Please note that there are some [breaking changes](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/commit/25311c7eed80068b6abeb872582a8a216bb0b3f8#L0L28) coming in 1.5.2 - DefaultHandler name was removed and internally handler has been turned into auto-created smart pointer (that's the main reason we had to obsolete DefaultHandler so existing code would not pass stack-created handler to the smart pointer, it was not a good design to start with). So, in 1.5.2, explicit handler creation will not be needed anymore for default parsing:

```
std::string json = "{ \"test\" : null }";
Parser parser;
Var result = parser.parse(json);
```

If you are concerned with performance, note also that Poco::JSON parser speed, as it stands now, is poor and we will be using either the [very fast](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/blob/json-benchmark/JSON/samples/Benchmark/src/Benchmark.cpp#L59) parser from [Poco::Web::JSON](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/blob/json-benchmark/Web/include/Poco/Web/JSONParser.h#L78) or something faster (if we can find/write it). Bottom line, 1.5.x is still W.I.P.

Hope this helps.

EDIT:

[Benchmarks](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/blob/json-benchmark/JSON/samples/Benchmark/src/Benchmark.cpp#L59) on Windows and Mac (~15MB JSON file):

**Windows**

> Poco::JSON:      1 195 313 [us]
>   Poco::Web::JSON: 403 320 [us]
>   json-parser:     321 289 [us]
>   libjson:         610 352 [us]

**MAC (clang)**

> Poco::JSON:      480 965 [us]
>   Poco::Web::JSON: 176 297 [us]
>   json-parser:     220 172 [us]

Comment: And it has the characteristics of a SAX-parser?

Comment: In 1.5.2, the default handler (ParseHandler) behaves more DOM-like (i.e. retains the whole tree in memory); end-user can easily provide a handler with SAX-like behavior.